# materalized view not getting refresh

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

created below MV but not getting updated even after refresh interval is defined while created MV on base table

```
 Create Materialized view sim_job
    
       refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (sysdate+1/1440) with rowid as
    SELECT TIMESTAMP,
    
     SUM(fs_count) AS fs_count
    
    
FROM
  (SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY') AS TIMESTAMP,
    COUNT(UNIQUE A.JID)                         AS FS_COUNT
  FROM LAS_ACT_PROD A,
    LAS_LOGIN B
  WHERE A.ID             IN ('LAS020')
  AND B.ROLE             IN ('TS_SW_TCH','TS_SE_TCH','TS_W_TCH','TS_W_TCH')
  AND TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP)       = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
  AND A.ID                 =B.ID
  AND TRUNC(B.LOGINTIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
  GROUP BY B.ROLE,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY')
  )
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: If you are actually using 11g, when you create this materialized view, there will be a job created in `dba_jobs` to refresh it.  Are you seeing that job?  Are there failures?  Are there errors in the alert log?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be suspect: `TIMESTAMP` is a *data type* not a column value.

The table in `FROM` clause is missing.

Anyway this works:

```
create table tab as 
select rownum fs_count
from dual 
connect by level <= 10;

Create Materialized view sim_job
   refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (sysdate+1/1440) with rowid as
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP TS,
 SUM(fs_count) AS fs_count
FROM tab;
```

The last refresh date can be queried with

```
select LAST_REFRESH_DATE from user_mviews where MVIEW_NAME = 'SIM_JOB';

LAST_REFRESH_DATE  
-------------------
10.08.2021 20:07:50
```

If you repeat it one minute later you should see a new refresh

```
LAST_REFRESH_DATE  
-------------------
10.08.2021 20:08:50
```

If not, check dependent on your Oracle Version either `USER_JOBS` or `USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS` if the job that refresh the MV is running (i.e. is not broken).

For Oracle 11 you get the `job` ID with

```
select owner, name, rname, REFGROUP, job, interval, to_char(next_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') next_date 
from DBA_REFRESH_CHILDREN ;
```

Than

```
 select * from USER_JOBS where  JOB = '<job>';
```

Note also that you must have set the `job_queue_processes` to a non zero value to be able to run jobs.

```
 select value from v$parameter where name = 'job_queue_processes';
```

Comment: base query is  added, materialized view created with refresh every minute but it's not getting refreshed automatically ...how can we fix it

Comment: Add the results of the last three queries from my answer. This is the *key* to the troubleshooting @bp_db